# Payment method doesn't show up in checkout page frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend

I've been trying to implement a payment method into our store, however, when i check the checkout process, it says it can't be completed since there are no payment methods enabled, i'm using Magento 1.9.2 and i'm using the hellowired theme, i've enabled multiple payment methods, however none of them are working.

The website URL is: ittd.nl/magento

A very annoying problem,  could anyone here help me out, so customers can buy online at our store?

Many Thanks!

Clay

Comment: What payment methods are you trying to enable? This problem could be caused by many things. Maybe you should connect your Magento store to the payment method's API.

Comment: I'm trying the standard ones like moneybookers and the defaults, tried using a extension of a 3rd party, like IcePay and Multisafepay,  however, none of them work.

Comment: Have you connected to their API's? Cleared cache after installing any of these modules?

Comment: No,  how can i connect to the API's?  is there like, a standard way to do so or should i get them from the devs websites, etc?

Comment: Please read the documentation from their websites. https://www.multisafepay.com/documentation/doc/Magento/

Comment: I've deleted Multisafepay actually, since it did not work the first time, i will redownload it again and read the documentation, however, what about the default payment methods of magento?  do they have API's too, which i need to connect?

Comment: If you are using PayPal for example, you should connect PayPal within Magento to your PayPal account. Other payment method's that come with Magento dont require external connections. When you use MultisafePay, your Magento store must be connected with their system. This is done through API. Read the documentation and everything will probably work.

Comment: Alright, is there any way to have a payment method that isn't MultiSafePay?  i've tried the standard ones and they don't work, they don't show up in the checkout page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings for payment gateways is not necessarily easy, especially if you've never set them up before.

For PayPal, you have to 1) have a PayPal account and 2) it has to be a business account.

With any gateway, you have to have an account established with the payment gateway provider first (PayPal, Moneybookers, Authorize.net, etc.). You can simply enable a payment method and have it show up.

See http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/configuration/sales/payment-methods.html for documentation on setting up Payment methods. You should probably also take a look at buying [Mastering Magento](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/mastering-magento) (yes, I wrote it) to help you in operating your Magento store.

Good luck!